# transform multiindex column dataframe to long table

Tags: pandas, multi-level

I have the below Excel table that I would like to transform into something that is easier to analyze. I struggle how to use python to transform this into the desired format.

[Original Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn6yW.png)

The desired format is as below:

[Target format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwTNZ.png)

I use the Pandas read_excel function to import that table but struggle to convert it into the desired format.

I tried to convert this via "wide_to_long" function but failed to the multilevel nature of that data.

Comment: review the stackoverflow guidelines to provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome! It is better if you post actual data samples rather than images of your data. Here's a list of reasons as well as some tips on how to format your posts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

One reason is that, for example, I would like to help you, but by the time I look at the second image, I have forgotten the first. 

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use picture examples when asking questions. You should provide code to generate source data.

Try this:

```
tmp = df.stack(0).reset_index()
result = (pd.wide_to_long(
    df=tmp,
    stubnames=['Name', 'Weight'],
    i=[*tmp][:3],
    j='Index')
    .reset_index())
print(result)
```